# XSD unique element XPath limitations

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, unique, xsd-1.0

In order to allow an element to appear multiple times but restrict it to element values only being allowed once, I'm applying the `unique` element. I've only got it working in an inefficient manner due to the XPath limitations within XSD 1.0 though. XSD 1.1 is unfortunately not an option for me.

Below is a simplified version of the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
    <xs:simpleType name="DeliveryMethod">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="POST"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="DIGITALARCHIVE"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="Mailpack">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="deliveryMethod" type="DeliveryMethod"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Letter">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Mailpack">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="batch">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:string"/>

                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="letter" type="Letter">
                        <xs:unique name="oneOfEachDeliveryMethodType">
                            <xs:selector xpath="deliveryMethod"/>
                            <xs:field xpath="." />
                        </xs:unique>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batch>
    <id>123</id>
    <letter>
        <deliveryMethod>POST</deliveryMethod>
        <deliveryMethod>DIGITALARCHIVE</deliveryMethod>
        <deliveryMethod>DIGITALARCHIVE</deliveryMethod>
        <content>Narf!</content>
    </letter>
</batch>
```

This works as expected and gives me the error that "DIGITALARCHIVE" is included twice.
The problem is that this method forces me to include the `unique` element in each possible extended `Mailpack` type.
So if I e.g. introduce a `Parcel` type as an extension of `Mailpack` then I have to duplicate the same `unique` element from the `batch/letter` element in the new `batch/parcel` element.

Making the `unique` element part of the `deliveryMethod` element as below is not an option because the `..` parent selector is not allowed in XSD XPath.

```
<xs:complexType name="Mailpack">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="deliveryMethod" type="DeliveryMethod">
            <xs:unique name="oneOfEachDeliveryMethodType">
                <xs:selector xpath="deliveryMethod"/>
                <xs:field xpath=".." />
            </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Making it part of the `batch` element directly resulted in the same issue.

How can I include the `unique` element only once but make it count for all extensions of `Mailpack`? (if at all)

Comment: I suppose you can't use XSD 1.1, is that true?

Comment: @sergioFC: I'm afraid XSD 1.1 is not an option, no. I would have loved to use it, but even after 3 years an essential application does not support it yet.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to wrap the <deliveryMethod> list in a <MailPack> element.

Comment: @sergioFC: how would that make a difference? Where would you place the `unique` element after that?

Comment: Inside the element containing the <deliveryMethod> list. Note that in my answer I've called it <deliveryMethodsList> instead of <MailPack>.

Comment: Is my alternative solution valid for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping the `<deliveryMethod>` elements in a (for example) `<deliveryMethodsList>` element you can move the `unique` element so you only have to write it once.

As an example you only need to replace your `Mailpack` *complexType* with the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="Mailpack">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="deliveryMethodsList">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="deliveryMethod" type="DeliveryMethod"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <!-- Unique is only placed here -->
            <xs:unique name="oneOfEachDeliveryMethodType">
                <xs:selector xpath="deliveryMethod"/>
                <xs:field xpath="." />
            </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And now you don't need the `unique` element in the *letters* list:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="letter" type="Letter" />
```

Now the following example is not valid as `<deliveryMethod>DIGITALARCHIVE</deliveryMethod>` appears twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batch>
    <id>123</id>
    <letter>
        <deliveryMethodsList>
            <deliveryMethod>POST</deliveryMethod>
            <deliveryMethod>DIGITALARCHIVE</deliveryMethod>
            <deliveryMethod>DIGITALARCHIVE</deliveryMethod>
        </deliveryMethodsList>
        <content>Narf!</content>
    </letter>
</batch>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. It's even cleaner by having the `deliveryMethod` elements wrapped in a separate element instead of having them 'floating' in the `letter` element directly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I was not sure if this would be valid for your needs. You are welcome.

Comment: Would you mind correcting your own post by changing the caps on `DeliveryMethodsList` to `deliveryMethodsList`? The moderation twats rejected my edit, invalidly stating it does not improve it's accuracy.  Inconsistent styles and references are now being used.

Comment: Of course, and you're right, it is better and corrected now.